# Excel Pivot Table - ordinal position of PivotItems does not match what is diaplayed on the screen

Tags: vba, excel

When comparing:
PivotTable.PivotFields("field1").PivotItems
to:
PivotTable.PivotFields("field2").PivotItems

The ordinal positions of the items when consumed from VBA do not match that which is displayed on the screen.

Note that in the code below, I have explicitly set both PivotFields to visible (xlColumnField), and set the position of one of them to 1.

On the screen, the position of the PivotItems within each of the two PivotFields lines up accordingly (obviously).  But when in this state, you examine the items through VBA, the ordinal position within each collection, as well as the .Position Property, are different than what is displayed on the screen.

Is there a way to properly access these so I can find proper matches between the individual PivotItems across multiple PivotFields?  (Or some other way of going about it?)

```
Sub debugPivotTableFieldData(pt As PivotTable)
    Dim aPivotField As PivotField
    Dim aPivotItem As PivotItem
    Dim iField As Integer

    Debug.Print pt.PivotFields("Airport").Orientation
    Debug.Print pt.PivotFields("Name").Orientation

    pt.PivotFields("Airport").Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlColumnField
    pt.PivotFields("Name").Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlColumnField
    pt.PivotFields("Airport").Position = 1

    Debug.Print "DEBUG PIVOT TABLE: " & pt.Name
    For iField = 1 To pt.PivotFields("Airport").PivotItems.Count
        Debug.Print pt.PivotFields("Airport").PivotItems(iField) & " - " & pt.PivotFields("Airport").PivotItems(iField).Position
    Next
    For iField = 1 To pt.PivotFields("Name").PivotItems.Count
        Debug.Print pt.PivotFields("Name").PivotItems(iField) & " - " & pt.PivotFields("Name").PivotItems(iField).Position
    Next
    For iField = 1 To pt.PivotFields("Airport").PivotItems.Count
        Debug.Print pt.PivotFields("Airport").PivotItems(iField) & " - " & pt.PivotFields("Name").PivotItems(iField)
    Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm 95% certain this is just the way it is.  I think the ordinal position of the items in the collection has no relation whatsoever to what is displayed on the screen, or what the value of .Position is for each element.

So to properly set the column positions for the pivot items in two pivot fields at once, I filled a Scripting.Dictionary with the distinct values (of the two fields) from the PivotTable.PivotCache.Recordset....then, iterate on the dictionary items, and you can access the the PivotItems in each pivot field **by name** and set their .Position that way so they have matching sorts.