# Excel VBA move pivot item to last position

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a pivot table with a bunch of countries but one item in the table is a group called "Other". I want to sort the table in descending order except for the item "Other" which should always be last. I tried sorting in descending order first and then overwriting the position of "Other" manually but whenever I do that the order of the whole table changes again...

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(tblname).PivotFields("Country").AutoSort xlDescending, "Sum of Weight"
```

This works fine.

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(tblname).PivotFields("Country").PivotItems("Other").Position = 8
```

This moves "Other" into last position but simultaneously changes the order of all other previously sorted items.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: my original approach had a problem due to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5160206/478884
Basically you can't rely on a PivotItem's `Position` accurately reflecting the displayed order of the item in the pivot table.

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim pt As PivotTable, pf As PivotField
    
    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1) 'for example
    Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Country")
    
    ListItems pf, "Before sort"
    
    pf.AutoSort xlDescending, "Sum of Weight"
    
    ListItems pf, "After sort, before resetting Position"
    FixPosition pf   'reset the pivotitems' `Position` property
    ListItems pf, "After resetting Position"
    
    pf.PivotItems("Other").Position = pf.PivotItems.Count 'now this works...
    
    ListItems pf, "Before reorder"

End Sub

'Reset the Position property of each pivotitem for a pivotfield
'  to match its *displayed* order
Sub FixPosition(pf As PivotField)
    Dim arr, i
    arr = pf.DataRange.Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        pf.PivotItems(arr(i, 1)).Position = i
    Next i
End Sub

'For debugging: list pivot items and their Position
'Must be >1 pivot item or the `.Value` won't be an array 
'Adapt if you need to handle that
Sub ListItems(pf As PivotField, when As String)
    Dim pi As PivotItem
    Debug.Print "-------" & when & "---------"
    For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
        Debug.Print pi.Name, pi.Position
    Next pi
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but ran into another problem:

When sorting the items according to "Sum of Weight", the order on the sheet changes but when accessing the item positions in VBA they remain in alphabetical order. So when VBA loops through each pi in your code, it stores their positions in alphabetical order not in the order they appear on screen.

Very weird. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: I also tried another way with the same result:

 `n = 0
 For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
        If pi.Name <> "Other" Then
            pi.Position = pi.Position - n
        Else
            pi.Position = pf.PivotItems.Count
            n = 1
        End If
 Next pi`

Comment: You're right - there's no change in the order of the items (based on their `Position` property) after sorting, even though the list is clearly changed...   I somehow missed that in my testing.   I will update...